# How to make the shadow of an object not cover a character in Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D game on Unity and I want to add shadows to objects. Some of them should cover the character so that the character becomes darker. But the shadows of some objects should not cover the character because it looks unrealistic. Here is an example:

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGAxN.png)

Here you can see that the shadow from the table covers part of the character. I want to make the shadow appear to be behind the character, but I don't want to make this shadow a sprite.